# Why isn't this message subject encoded properly? (php mail)

Tags: php, html, email, encoding, utf-8

I use this code to send an email:

```
$headers="MIME-Version: 1.0"."\n";
$headers.="Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"."\n";
$headers.="From: $name <$email>"."\n";

mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $text, $headers, '-fnoreply@domain.com');
```

If I use special characters Å Ä Ö from the swedish alphabet, they are not encoded properly, so they turn up like `Ã¶ for ö`.

However, this doesn't happen if I change the `$to` variable to a gmail account email, then they are shown correctly.

Anybody got any idea?

Thanks

UPDATE:

When I `echo $name`, the name is displayed correctly, in utf8, with all special chars nicely shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should convert input text to UTF-8 using iconv, I think GMail does that for you.

```
$text =  iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text), "UTF-8//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $text)
```

Also check that you PHP page is Unix UTF-8.

OR

You can use [phpMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/PHPMailer_v5.1.zip/download) or libmail